# Wrapping select dropdown navigation in nav tag

Tags: html

I have a navigation menu on mobile which is a select field with some Javascript to redirect to the data-href attribute.

```
<select>
   <option value="" data-href="/somepage">Some page</option>
   <option value="" data-href="/anotherpage">Another page</option>
</select>
```

My question is pretty simple: Would it be preferred to wrap a navigation menu of this kind in a `<nav>` tag?

Comment: Probably doesn't matter too much for SEO, if that's what you're worried about. Search engines will scan the sitemap and doesnt need links. It might matter a lot for screen readers, although an attribute of `role="navigation"` could solve that just the same. 

Mozilla prefers `nav` to `role="navigation"` though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Navigation_Role

Comment: @Levi Not exactly for SEO, more for accessibility and best practices. Mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: Best practice would probably be to use anchor tags and not a select tag. I've often done the same though.

Answer (score 1):

The `nav` element defines a set of navigation links.
In your case you seem to have all links in the same select.
If you are using only one select, then I should not use the `nav` element.

In case you have multiple selects, you can use the `nav` element to make them into a set.

My question to you is why even use the select elements?
You could make it much easier by using:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Somepage</a>
      <a href="#">Another page</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```